# How to show a square of colour in an activity

Tags: android

I was using a textView, setting its background color but as soon as i remove the text it shrinks to nothing and so cant be seen.

Is there an control that i can use to simply show a square palette of color?

My 2 colour squares - i want to show the user the current colours picked from a colour picker....

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:id="@+id/textView_primaryColor"
        android:hint="Set Primary Color: Tap here"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:id="@+id/textView_secondaryColor"
        android:hint="Set Secondary Color: Tap here"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

public void choosePrimaryColor(final Context context, int defaultColor) {
    AmbilWarnaDialog dialogColor = new AmbilWarnaDialog(context, defaultColor, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
            textView_primaryColor.setBackgroundColor(color);
            textView_primaryColor.setHint("");
            primaryColorChosen =  "#"+Integer.toHexString(color);
            Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    dialogColor.show();
}

public void chooseSecondaryColor(final Context context, int defaultColor) {
    final AmbilWarnaDialog dialogColor = new AmbilWarnaDialog(context, defaultColor, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
            textView_secondaryColor.setBackgroundColor(color);
            textView_secondaryColor.setHint("");
            secondaryColorChosen = "#"+Integer.toHexString(color);
            Toast.makeText(context, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    dialogColor.show();
}
```

Comment: change the width of TextView from `wrap_content` to something like `match_parent` or `fill_parent` which will solve your TextView width issue.

Comment: Ok cool. Im not sure this will work as i have 2 textviews side by side, is there no better control to use?

Comment: you can hardcode the widths in `dp`s...which control are you referring to? color picker?

Comment: I have imported a color picker as there was no native controls that allow me to pick a color. The result then sets the background of a textview- this seems to be using textview incorrectly but maybe not

Comment: could you please show the code..

Comment: try adding `textView_primaryColor.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));`after `textView_primaryColor.setBackgroundColor(color);`

Comment: the width is already set to match_parent

Comment: then whats the problem that you are facing?

Comment: When the hint is removed the textview shrinks to nothing and so i cant see the color of the textview. Im trying to display a color to user- whats best way to do this?

Comment: Maybe dont use textview control?

Comment: Try adding a linear layout or relative layout and then set the background of the new layout to show the user which color he selected.

Comment: Ok that sounds gd. Il try that and get back to u in a few days. Thx a mil

Comment: Oh great..please do update me with the result @Fearghal.. Meanwhile I'll just add that as my answer..Could you please give me an upvote..

Comment: Ok add an answer with the edited xml i should put in. Have it include textview that contains hint that i will then dynamically set to blank. Il then set the layouts to the color i want

Answer (score 0):

On seeing your comments, I think your intention is to show the user which color he selected from the color picker.

For that my suggestion would be to add a new Layout(Linear or Relative) and then set the color chosen by the user as the background for the new Layout that you just created.

Add this to your xml

```
<LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/layout_primaryColor"
          android:layout_height="100dp"     
          android:layout_width="100dp"/>
```

and then in your activity, add

```
LinearLayout primaryColorLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_primaryColor);
```

Now, to set the background color, add

```
primaryColorLayout .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Comment: What is the reason to use a LinearLayout rather than any other View?

Comment: I just can't decide which one to use, but I think a LinearLayout inside a parent ViewGroup might not be as good for performance. Don't you think so?

Comment: no idea about that @Solace.. will have to research.. ;)

Comment: I just realized that I am getting into 'premature optimization'. Let's dismiss it with this quote: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%" (Donald Knuth). I'll use LinearLayout.